# <JS>Need a function that uses a while loop to add "!!!" to the end of the string elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Tried searching for this unsuccessfully.  I need to use a while loop to add "!!!" to the end of each element in a string array.  I've tried several different ways, the latest of which is:

```
var facts = ["He was the last Beatle to learn to drive", "He was never a vegetarian", "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
"He hated the sound of his own voice"];

function johnLennonFacts(facts) {
var newFacts=[];
var i = 0;
while (i < 4) {

newFacts[i] = facts[i] +="!!!";
i++;
}
return newFacts;
}
```

Must be all js no libraries that I am aware of.  I am new to code (obviously).  I understand that there may be better ways to do this, but I have to use a while loop.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove = from += and it will work

Comment: do you need to change the initial array or create the new one?

Comment: `+=` is an assignment operator. If you are just concatenating the !!! just use `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have to do is append the "!!!" to the array items - you can do this without creating a new array - just alter the existing array. The following console logs the altered array. Also remember that its not enough to have the function - in order for it to work - you need to call it as well. I also changed it to have the length of the array as the upper limit - rather than hard coding ti to be 4 - this is better because if you change the content of the array - you don't want to have to worry about changing the hard coded value as well.

Also the "+=" operator is a short hand way of saying the following:...
facts[i] =  facts[i] + "!!!" ...; which works in this case since we are changing the value of the initial array.

```js
//sets the array
var facts = ["He was the last Beatle to learn to drive", "He was never a vegetarian", "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
"He hated the sound of his own voice"];

//alters the array when called
function johnLennonFacts(facts) {
  var i = 0;
    while (i < facts.length) {
       facts[i] += "!!!";
     i++;
    }
    console.log(facts);
  }
  
 //calls the function to alter the array
 johnLennonFacts(facts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var facts = ["He was the last Beatle to learn to drive", "He was never a vegetarian", "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
"He hated the sound of his own voice"];

function johnLennonFacts(facts) {
    var newFacts=[];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < facts.length) {
        newFacts[i] = facts[i] + "!!!";
        i++;
    }
    return newFacts;
}

console.log(johnLennonFacts(facts));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var facts = ["He was the last Beatle to learn to drive", "He was never a vegetarian", "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
"He hated the sound of his own voice"];

function johnLennonFacts(facts) {
var newFacts=[];
var i = 0;
while (i < 4) {

newFacts[i] = facts[i] +"!!!";
i++;
}
return newFacts;
}
```

You don't need to add a `=` to the string because you are already setting a string. Btw is `+=` an assignment operator. Also don't forget to call your function in your code.

Answer (score -1):

This worked.  I didn't have to call or console.log because the JS I'm running is inside an IDE (for a course)  The clarification about the += really helped.  Thanks to all that helped, really appreciated it.

```js
//sets the array
var facts = ["He was the last Beatle to learn to drive", "He was never a vegetarian", "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
"He hated the sound of his own voice"];

//alters the array when called
function johnLennonFacts(facts) {
  var i = 0;
    while (i < facts.length) {
       facts[i] += "!!!";
     i++;
    }
    console.log(facts);
  }
  
 //calls the function to alter the array
 johnLennonFacts(facts)
```